# Typescript: Comparing a text from an element with a string is giving me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTMSDeviceForm' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, protractor

In my Protractor automation test, I am trying to find an element and compare the Linktext with a string. 
But I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTMSDeviceForm' of undefined".
P.S.: I am new to Protractor and working my way in it.

Thank you.

```
  **steps.ts file**  
      Then('CREATE WATERMELON TMS DEVICE form is displayed', async () => {
          //added
          browser.sleep(3000);
          browser.TMS.createTMSDeviceForm.getText().then( function(currentText){
            expect(TMS.createTMSDeviceForm.getText()).to.equal("Create Watermelon TMS Device");
          }
        )
        });

[Error displayed][1]

     × Then CREATE WATERMELON TMS DEVICE form is displayed # stepDefinitions\steps.ts:82
           TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTMSDeviceForm' of undefined
               at C:\Users\dbhandary\Documents\TestAutomation\Sypha-Typescript\stepDefinitions\steps.ts:85:19
               at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
               at C:\Users\dbhandary\Documents\TestAutomation\Sypha-Typescript\JSFiles\stepDefinitions\steps.js:8:71
               at new Promise (<anonymous>)
               at __awaiter (C:\Users\dbhandary\Documents\TestAutomation\Sypha-Typescript\JSFiles\stepDefinitions\steps.js:4:12)
               at World.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dbhandary\Documents\TestAutomation\Sypha-Typescript\stepDefinitions\steps.ts:82:71)
       √ After # stepDefinitions\hooks.ts:14


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENwE.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I had to use the variable I got the text into for comparison in Expect. This resolved the issue.

```
**steps.ts file**  
  Then('CREATE WATERMELON TMS DEVICE form is displayed', async () => {
          //added
      browser.sleep(3000);
      browser.TMS.createTMSDeviceForm.getText().then( function(currentText){
      expect(currentText).to.equal("Create Watermelon TMS Device");
          })
  });
```